# convert images black background to white and white to black in python

Tags: python-3.x, image, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

[image]

I need to convert images black background to white and white char to black in images using python libaray. I tried with `ImageOps.invert`

```
im = Image.open('aa_comressed_32.png').convert('RGB')

im_invert = ImageOps.invert(im)

im_invert.save('aa_comressed_32opinvert.png')
```

or tried on matlab using:

```
f = misc.face(gray=True)  # retrieve a grayscale image

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(f, cmap=plt.cm.gray
```

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and format it properly by indenting lines of code with 4 spaces. Thank you.

Comment: Please also put back all the `import` statements that you have removed so others can run your code. Also, please explain what didn't work, or what results you got. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

import os, sys
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("image_path")

newsize = (128,128)
im1 = im.resize(newsize)

#im1_new = add_margin(im1, 20, 20, 20, 20, (255, 255, 255))

display(im1)
out = im1.convert("RGB")
out_rgb = out.convert("L")

display(out_rgb)